# Where is the gift?

Tags: achievements, eye-divine-cybermancy

The Gift achievement for E.Y.E Divine Cybermancy simply says:

> Pick up the gift.

Where is the gift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as your sent to the main hub you embark on your next mission when you appear to be air lifted in and given a variety of objectives. If you want an easier time turn down the difficulty.

For me I grabbed heavy armor, smg and the silenced sniper rifle with loads of ammo and a few grenades. If you head off to your left there is a large number of enemies that appear around a garage looking structure. It also appears guys will re-pop in some areas or the zone is just very large.

I just sat around killing enemies until I saw what looked to be a giftbox drop from one of them.

The game reminds me of a blend of elder scrolls, deus ex and half life.

Comment: I did this and eventually got my gift as well.

Answer (score 3):

The Gift appears to be a (random?) drop from a [killed enemy](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2287819):

> The Gift is a white box bound by green wrapping that drops from a killed enemy - in my case, from a Jian Shang Di light-armoured minigun soldier in Purge (although more Gifts dropped from subsequent enemies). Simply walk over it; it acts like a normal research briefcase but grants the achievement.

Other responses in the thread say that you've got to unlock the Forgotten Center mission in Temple HQ (you'll need to play the first couple of missions to get this far) and then you'll find both of the holiday achievements in that mission.

Comment: I see, I was looking for it all over the initial base area.

Comment: when do these gifts start showing up?  I'm in the first mission and I haven't seen a single one.

Comment: Edited, can you choose the Forgotten Center mission in Temple HQ yet?  I think you need to clear the first mission or couple of missions before you can access this content.